# How to extract images from Statuses(Facebook style publisher) and display in seperate page?

Tags: status-messages

I am using statuses module in my project which is working fine for my requirement. but my new requirement is, i need to extract the user posted pictures(not user profile pictures) in statuses module and need to display in new page along with the author of images posted. If images are more than one it should shown like album or some slide show.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's related to the statuses module at all. It seems it can be a very different story, unrelated to that module. One easy way is to use bridges like janrain (rpx).

Comment: Thanks for reply. But there is no concept related to JANRAIN.. I need like pin boards for all users who got registered and who and all posted in my site using facebook style micropublisher.It means i want all users albums in a different page, is there any way to achieve it through views?

Comment: I see... I think I fail to understand what is needed.